# How can I detect a clicked element in an Editor Script?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to implement a custom LayoutManager, e.g. a HorizontalLayout. (Yes I know, that this already exists, but I want my own behaviour) So when I let my script calculate the width, that works. But now I want to adjust the width of one Element and let the script recalculate the width of the other elements accordingly, I run into the problem, that the width is "locked" because the script is calculating all the time. So I want to tell the script, that it should only recalculate for the elements which are not clicked on the layout for the moment. I hope something like this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UnityEditor.Selection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection.html) class to determine which objects are selected.

For example, when iterating over child objects to determine whether to adjust their scale, you can test whether `UnityEditor.Selection.Contains(thisChild)`